# Any standard guide for Ruby WIN32OLE API?

Tags: ruby, api, win32ole

I searched a lot on this but haven't yet got any standard or rather systematic guide for Win32Ole in Ruby. Ruby on windows by David is very good but I need a complete, systematic standard tutorial for WIN32OLE ruby APIs.

Please suggest!

Thanks

Pradyumna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear you may not find one. David Mullet is [working on a book](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2009/08/about-book.html) but that rather implies that it's still some considerable time away from publication.

> I need a complete, systematic standard
>   tutorial for WIN32OLE ruby APIs.

How "complete", "systematic" and "standard" do you really need it to be? You have to consider that someone needs to have the motivation to produce such a tutorial, which would be a substantial piece of work to undertake for no reward; that's why a book is in preparation - then we can pay David for his expertise!

So we may need to modify your need to be more satisfiable by current reality: are there particular problem(s) you are trying to solve? Could you put some more specific questions here?

Comment: Ok, Anyways Thanks... I think, until david complete his book, i might need to look in to the rdoc all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about posting the same question when I came across your post.  I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but I have had some success with Ruby and Excel.  I find that if you can create an Excel macro that does something similar to what you would like Ruby to do, you can more or less 'rubyfy' the macro code and access all the same methods and attributes in your Ruby code.  I was able to figure out how to get Ruby to create Excel graphs, and cell color coding this way.  If the software you want to interact with has a similar macroing tool, you may be able to work out how to use ruby to interact with that software.  I do look forward to the book that Mike mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problems are with win32OLE rather than with ruby, I'd be half tempted to look for guides in other scripting languages, such as perl.

Comment: I suggest you take Vbscript as example, there are lots of vbs scripts (including vba code) that do this kind of stuff using ActiveX Com objects and that you can convert to Ruby using win32OLE. Of course i'm biased by programming in both languages.