# VSS automation with ruby win32ole

Tags: ruby, visual-sourcesafe, win32ole

I am trying to automate some of operation and gather information from a microsoft visual SourceSafe6.0 repo, using ruby1.9 and WIN32OLE gem.

it is possible to create a OLE object with

`require 'WIN32OLE'`

`v = WIN32OLE.new 'SourceSafe'`

but I'm confused with what to next. `v.ole_methods` seems not quite informative.

when using WIN32OLE, Is there any hint about this, or general guide about guessing/inspecting such interfaces?

========
not that duplicate of [Any standard guide for Ruby WIN32OLE API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326303/any-standard-guide-for-ruby-win32ole-api) , that blog gives useful information like `WIN32OLE#ole_methods` and examples on some other program. not about vss though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop(v=VS.80).aspx

When experimenting with Win32OLE I tend to open up an irb session and just experiment seeing what objects I can get hold of.

You need to read the API documentation though as it's hard to work out what types to pass and how many parameters methods have, otherwise.