# cannot send email via outlook in ruby

Tags: ruby, email, outlook, ole

I have a script where the syntax works using irb but not via the ruby program.
The script fails at the message1.Send line. However this syntax works when I execute it under irb.

```
**P:/RubyAutoEmail.rb:23:in `method_missing': (in OLE method `Send': ) (WIN32OLERuntimeError)**
    OLE error code:4096 in Microsoft Outlook
      Outlook does not recognize one or more names.
    HRESULT error code:0x80020009
      Exception occurred.
        from P:/RubyAutoEmail.rb:23:in `block in sendemail'
        from P:/RubyAutoEmail.rb:12:in `each'
        from P:/RubyAutoEmail.rb:12:in `sendemail'
        from P:/RubyAutoEmail.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

For example. here you can see that the message1.Send works

```
    irb(main):002:0> require 'win32ole'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
=> #<WIN32OLE:0x0000000327a8c8>
irb(main):004:0> mapi = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
=> #<WIN32OLE:0x000000030e53a0>
irb(main):005:0> drafts = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(16)
=> #<WIN32OLE:0x000000032a8778>
irb(main):006:0>  drafts.Items.each do |message|
irb(main):007:1*  if message.Subject =~ /test email/i
irb(main):008:2> message1 = outlook.CreateItem(0)
irb(main):009:2> message1.Subject
irb(main):010:2> message1.To='junkone2@dd.com'
irb(main):011:2> message1.Send
irb(main):012:2> end
irb(main):013:1> end
=> nil
```

However, when I write it using a script, it fails.

```
    require 'win32ole'

    def sendemail(outlook, foldernumber, templatename,nameplaceholder,actualname,emailid)
    mapi = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
 drafts = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(foldernumber)

 # Iterate over messages in a folder:

 drafts.Items.each do |message|

    # Your code here...
 if message.Subject =~ /test email/i
# if message.Subject.downcase.include?(templatename.downcase)
message1 = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message1.Subject=message.Subject
message1.Body=message.Body
message1.Body=message1.Body.gsub(nameplaceholder,actualname)
message1.To=emailid
message1.Save
message1.Send

  end
    end  
    end

    outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')


# constant numbers
#https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219371(v=office.11).aspx

 sendemail(outlook,16, "test email","<TBD>","Junkee","junkone97@gmail")

 #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593166/whats-the-easiest-way-to-send-a-message-through-outlook-with-ruby
```

Comment: As a note, it's probably a lot easier to send email from Ruby to your SMTP server directly than through Outlook.

Comment: see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1):

I did not use a proper email address and I fixed it.it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid email address, use the same one you used in your IRB test case.  It looks like perhaps this line should be moved before your loop:

```
outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
```

So try:

```
require 'win32ole'

def sendemail(outlook, foldernumber, templatename,nameplaceholder,actualname,emailid)
  mapi = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
  drafts = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(foldernumber)
  outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')

  # Iterate over messages in a folder:

  drafts.Items.each do |message|

    # Your code here...
    if message.Subject =~ /test email/i
      message1 = outlook.CreateItem(0)
      message1.Subject=message.Subject
      message1.Body=message.Body
      message1.Body=message1.Body.gsub(nameplaceholder,actualname)
      message1.To=emailid
      message1.Save
      message1.Send
    end
  end  
end

sendemail(outlook, 16, "test email","<TBD>","Junkee","junkone2@dd.com")
```